# ActiveAdmin separating scopes by groups is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've seen in the doc https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html that I can separate my scopes in groups, which is exactly what I need since I don't want my 'pending' scope to look like a third option of my 'deleted/not deleted' scopes.

So I tried adding

`scope :pending, group: :other_group` 
but nothing happened.

What is the name that I need to pass to the group? Do I have to have it defined?

I'm using `active_admin_paranoia` which adds two default scopes (deleted, not deletes). Might that be the problem?

Comment: Okay you want to 2 scopes, one for pending and other should display for deleted not deleted. is it ?

Comment: No, I already have the three scopes. The deleted/not deleted is generated automatically by the gem. I want to GROUP the scopes as the doc suggests. I want to see different groups of tabs in my index page, where deleted/not deleted scopes are together, and peding scope is in other group.